# Handle exception of single object in mapping of Json Array to POJO Array using Gson in Android

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson, mapping

I'm reading Json array from third-party API and mapping it directly to POJO array using Gson. Frequently, I'm getting missing data for some of objects and all missing parameters have `"N/A"` value.

My POJO class mixed of `String` and `Double` variables, now when `"N/A"` is returned where `Double` value is expected, the app get crashed. Definitely, I can loop through them manually and skip objects with missing data, but I'm looking for alternative solution that help me to do same in mapping using Gson.

POJO class (Kotlin syntax)

```
class StockData(
    var symbol: String?,
    var name: String?,
    var currency: String?,
    var price: Double,
    @SerializedName("day_change")
    var dayChange: Double,
    @SerializedName("change_pct")
    var changePct: Double,
    var price90DayHigh: Double,
    var price90DayLow: Double
)
```

Mapping

```
val stockDataList = Gson().fromJson(response.body()!!.asJsonObject.get("data"),
                    Array<StockData>::class.java).toList()
```

Json with available data

```
{
    "symbol": "AAK.ST",
    "name": "AAK AB (publ)",
    "currency": "SEK",
    "price": "189.15",
    "price_open": "190.90",
    "day_high": "190.95",
    "day_low": "188.30",
    "52_week_high": "203.80",
    "52_week_low": "131.62",
    "day_change": "-1.35",
    "change_pct": "-0.71",
    "close_yesterday": "190.50",
    "market_cap": "47993210000",
    "volume": "110641",
    "volume_avg": "476416",
    "shares": "253730934",
    "stock_exchange_long": "Stockholm Stock Exchange",
    "stock_exchange_short": "OMX",
    "timezone": "CET",
    "timezone_name": "Europe/Stockholm",
    "gmt_offset": "3600",
    "last_trade_time": "2020-02-21 17:29:54",
    "pe": "32.60",
    "eps": "5.32"
}
```

Json with missing data

```
{
    "symbol": "HEMF-PREF.ST",
    "name": "N/A",
    "currency": "N/A",
    "price": "0.00",
    "price_open": "N/A",
    "day_high": "N/A",
    "day_low": "N/A",
    "52_week_high": "N/A",
    "52_week_low": "N/A",
    "day_change": "N/A",
    "change_pct": "N/A",
    "close_yesterday": "N/A",
    "market_cap": "N/A",
    "volume": "N/A",
    "volume_avg": "N/A",
    "shares": "N/A",
    "stock_exchange_long": "Stockholm Stock Exchange",
    "stock_exchange_short": "OMX",
    "timezone": "CET",
    "timezone_name": "Europe/Stockholm",
    "gmt_offset": "3600",
    "last_trade_time": "N/A",
    "pe": "N/A",
    "eps": "N/A"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be 2 ways:
1.You create GsonAdapter adapter , like

```
class StockDataAdapter: TypeAdapter<StockData> {
   fun read(reader: JsonReader): StockData {
      ....handle actual json parsing here, setting default value to field if parsing failed
    }
}
```

and then

```
val gson =GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(StockData.class,  StockDataAdapter()).create();
val stockDataList = gson.fromJson(response.body()!!.asJsonObject.get("data"),
                Array<StockData>::class.java).toList()
```

2. You can make all fields String type and parse actual values in place, like

   class StockData(
       val symbol: String?,
       val name: String?,
       val currency: String?,
       val price: String,
       @SerializedName("day_change")
       val dayChange: String?,
       @SerializedName("change_pct")
       val changePct: String,
       val price90DayHigh: String,
       val price90DayLow: String
   ) {
   val priceAsDouble:Double 
      get() = try {price.toDouble()}catch(e:Exception){0.0}
   }

Comment: Both approaches seems correct. I wish to confirm an alternative for first approach, i.e. instead of writing parsing logic within custom `GsonAdapter`, what if we ignore parsing with `Gson()` and directly write logic in for loop of `JsonArray`. Which alternative will be more efficient?

Comment: It will be no difference with the first approach, actually.